# How to declare an ImageView in a class?

Tags: java, android

I have an `InsertStampActivity` witch contains 3 `EditText` and an `ImageView` received from phone's `gallery`. 
I need to create a class with those 3 editText and the image.

Here is my class:

```
public class Timbru {
    private int year;
    private String country;
    private float value;    }
```

I have also implement `construtor`, getters and setters for each parameter.

My question is how to implement the `imageView` in my class for further operations?

Comment: just keep the instance of the image view in your class as you are already keeping instance of String and you can provide getters an setters as well

Comment: You want to put ImageView and EditText inside an non-activity class?

Comment: @nhoxbypass yes, i need to use this class in an adapter.

Comment: Store the data for the view, not the view itself. It's the Adapter's purpose to turn the data into a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare your image in your class as a String.

```
public class Timbru {
   private int year;
   private String country;
   private float value;
   private String image;
}
```

Then, in your activity, convert the ImageView to a String like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourImage);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();


String imageToStoreInYourClass = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
```

And then you can also convert from the String to Bitmap back like this:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```